# Current user (not admin) appears in "Run as Administator"

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-server-2012, credentials, elevation

When I try to run some program as administrator, I always get dialog box asking me to choose user and type password. But I also get it with normal user, say, *George*. Moreover, I have logged in as *George*. This user is in groups *Users* and *Power Users*, but not *Administrators*. I want to see only administrators in this list as usual.

So, where can I specify which users I see after I click on *Run as Administrator* or simply remove user *George* from administrators list?

Deletion user from *Power Users* has no effect.
When I disable enumeration admins on elevation, user *George* remains in *Run as Administrator* dialog as before.

I have this problem on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012. It seems that I do something wrong.

Window that I see actually:
[image: 1]

Window that I want to see:
[image: 2]

Comment: Do you run a lot of different applications as the other user, or is it just a few specific ones?  If it's just a few, you could consider creating a shortcut that runs the "runas /user:[program]" command.  Then you'll just have your password to enter.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not solution for me. I need know where is my mistake and why normal user appers in administrators list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a year and a half, I am answering my own question, for which I found a solution.

*Power users* appear in such windows too. All I needed was to remove myself from this group.